# Launch iPad simulator from Instruments

Tags: xcode, ios, instruments

In Xcode, you can select an active target that will launch either into the iPad, or iPhone simulator. However, when launching an app from Instruments, I do not see any similar option.

How do you select the simulator you want to launch in Instruments?

Comment: This is a simulator, not an emulator.  What metrics could you be getting that are accurate compared to the target hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-launch-into-simulator-help/LaunchIntoSimulator.html),

1. Open Choose Target and find the application package compiled for the simulator
2. Open the drop down again, now you should be able to see Launch Options
3. In Launch Options select simulated device and iOS version:

[image: Launching iPad simulator from Instruments]

This should help you.

Comment: This is so very helpful! I spent so much time waiting for my app to boot up on iPad while profiling..